# How to make a crescent moon shape in HTML canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I need to make the following shape in HTML5 canvas. I have tried using cubic bezier arcs and also clipping two circles.

How can I make this shape?

Here's my work in progress, just cant get it right

https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/oeXbdg?editors=1010

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx1 = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx1.lineWidth = 2;

ctx1.beginPath();
ctx1.bezierCurveTo(4, 42, 0, 0, 42, 4);
ctx1.moveTo(4, 42);
ctx1.bezierCurveTo(4, 42, 0, 84, 42, 84);
ctx1.stroke();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx2.lineWidth = 2;

ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.arc(55, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx2.moveTo(165, 75);
ctx2.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx2.fill();
```

[image: Crescent Moon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using `globalCompositeOperation`

https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/oeXbdg?editors=1010

Answer (score 7):

### Circle circle boolean operation.

Incase anyone is interested in a programmatic solution the example below finds the intercept points of the two circles and uses those points to calculate the start and end angles for the outer and inner circle.

This is a little more flexible than a masking solution as it give you a path.

Snippet shows circle, move mouse over circle to see crescent solution. Not the stroke that would not be available if using a masking solution.

```js
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.height = canvas.width = 400;

const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
  const m = mouse;
 const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 m.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
 m.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY; 
 m.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : m.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));



// generic circle circle intercept function. Returns undefined if
// no intercept. 
// Circle 1 is center x1,y1 and radius r1
// Circle 2 is center x2,y2 and radius r2
// If points found returns {x1,y1,x2,y2} as two points.
function circleCircleIntercept(x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2){
    var x = x2 - x1;
    var y = y2 - y1;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    if(dist > r1 + r2 || dist < Math.abs(r1-r2)){
        return;  // no intercept return undefined
    }
    var a = (dist * dist - r1 * r1 + r2 *r2) / ( 2 * dist);
    var b = Math.sqrt(r2 * r2 - a * a);
    a /= dist;
    x *= a;
    y *= a;
    var mx = x2 - x;
    var my = y2 - y;
    dist = b / Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    x *= dist;
    y *= dist;
    return {
       x1 : mx-y,
       y1 : my+x,
       x2 : mx+y,
       y2 : my-x,
    };
}
// draws a crescent from two circles if possible
// If not then just draws the first circle
function drawCrescent(x1,y1,r1,x2,y2,r2){
    // The circle circle intercept finds points
    // but finding the angle of the points does not consider
    // the rotation direction and you end up having to do a lot of
    // checking (if statments) to determin the correct way to draw each circle
    // the following normalises the direction the circle are from each other
    // thus making the logic a lot easier
    
    var dist = Math.hypot(x2-x1,y2-y1);
    var ang = Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1);
    var intercepts = circleCircleIntercept(x1,y1,r1,x1 + dist,y1,r2);    
    if(intercepts === undefined){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x1, y1, r1, 0, PI2);
        if(dist < r1){
            ctx.moveTo(x2 + r2, y2);
            ctx.arc(x2, y2, r2, 0, PI2, true);
        }
       
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        return;
    }
    // get the start end angles for outer then inner circles
    const p = intercepts;
    var startA1 = Math.atan2(p.y1 - y1, p.x1 - x1) + ang; 
    var endA1 = Math.atan2(p.y2 - y1, p.x2 - x1) + ang; 
    var startA2 = Math.atan2(p.y1 - y1, p.x1 - (x1 + dist)) + ang; 
    var endA2 = Math.atan2(p.y2 - y1, p.x2 - (x1 + dist)) + ang; 

    ctx.beginPath();
    if(endA1 < startA1){
        ctx.arc(x1, y1, r1, startA1, endA1);
        ctx.arc(x2, y2, r2, endA2, startA2, true);
    }else{
        ctx.arc(x2, y2, r2, endA2, startA2);    
        ctx.arc(x1, y1, r1, startA1, endA1,true);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}


const outerRadius = 100;
const innerRadius = 80;

var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var globalTime;
ctx.font = "32px arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#999";


// main update function
function mainLoop(timer){
    globalTime = timer;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  
    ctx.fillText("Move mouse over circle",cw,40);    
    drawCrescent(cw, ch-40, outerRadius, mouse.x, mouse.y, innerRadius);

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```